# What should be the appropriate name of a log file

Tags: exception

I want to log my exceptions in a file. What will be the name of the file?

1. Error-ddmmyyyy.log
2. Log-ddmmyyyy.err
3. Log-ddmmyyyy.txt

or anything else?

Comment: Please specify the task that you want to log and the reason, why log names are critical

Answer (score 0):

If date is important, I would use yyyymmdd format: this is easier to get a sorted list. I would add hhmmss if relevant.

`.log` suffix is nice for me.

I would add the name of the command issuing exceptions as a prefix of the logfile.

Something like: `myCommand-20100315-114235.log`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can name your log files, you have to consider several factors:

Is your file generated by a special server or application in a group? Then you should add the name of the server to know where it does come from. 
Example:

```
Server1.log
```

In the log file there could be many levels of logging, if you want you can configure different files for different levels.
Example

```
Server1.info.log
Server1.err.log
```

You should add a date if your application runs for many days or if you want to keep track of errors for future reference, add it at the start of the name in yyyyMMdd format on windows or linux so they will be sorted by date automatically in command line commands or add it at the end if you want them more organized:

```
Server1.info.log.20100315 (Linux)
Server1.info.20100315.log (Win)
```

You can try with different combinations, it all depends on what sorting style and archiving style you want to achieve.

Comment: Is it required to maintain 3 different log files for DBPeople, for Business developer and for user.